# How to access loopback models without instantiating the server/app

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to code a script for creating some Users and link them to some other resources.

Checking loopback docs they told you to instantiate the app/server in order to acomplish it. https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Working+with+LoopBack+objects#WorkingwithLoopBackobjects-Fromacustomscript

But this method implies to get the app runing, a side effect which I'd like to avoid.

Any thoughts of how to access just the models but not the entire app?

Comment: why do you want the app to not run? what's its side-effect?

Comment: The app connects to a bunch of services so we just want one instance running and be able to run the script in parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we used for running the script without getting the web server initiated is a "work-arround" suggested in the loopback examples at github.

By adding this in your app.js...

```
// start the server if `$ node server.js`
if (require.main === module) {
  app.start();
}
```

...you get the app to start only if is directly called, not if it is required.

So with `var app = require('../app');` in our script we can fully access the app.models without running anything unnecessary.

Comment: I'm doing this for my users model but it gives app.models.user.find({where:{}}) cannot read property find of undefined in my custom-scipt which is inside server folder

Comment: I just checked again our script and we don't do anything else but requiring app.js on it...

Comment: yeah solved the issue. It was because of some kind of circular requiring.

Comment: This code appears to be the default in Loopback 3. I have found I needed to move the logic up a bit to be surrounding the `boot()` call too

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this in order to create some seed data via Loopback, you could create a `seedusers.js` file with the following code in it:

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');
var app = module.exports = loopback();

boot(app, __dirname);
```

Then run `node seedusers`

This would run any scripts in your boot directory, but not start a webserver.

Comment: so this will instantiate `app` used to create new `Users` and since it doesn't have server starting code, server will not start. did I state that correct?

Comment: @VishalKumar that's right. I'm assuming that this is what the OP wanted, but I guess we'll have to wait and see!

Comment: nice. I hope this is what he wanted because I don't know if we can create new `Users` without using `app`.

Comment: Yeah, what you are saying it´s what I want to acomplish. I just tried it and I get 'undefined' for the app.models.*. I will post the method we ended up using. (and sorry for the delay answering ;))

Comment: I'm doing exactly as I posted in my own script. `var mymodel = app.models.MyModel;` and I can start calling the built in Loopback methods to add data. Which part of app.models.* is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is trying to do this in Electron, your models will not get defined in `app.models` unless you override the `runtime.isServer`.

To override it, add this before requiring loopback:

```
let path = require('path');
let runtime = require(path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/loopback/lib/runtime'));
runtime.isBrowser = false;
runtime.isServer = true;
```